# Can I run a .bat file on a group of Azure servers?

Tags: sql-server, windows, azure, batch-file

I have created a .bat file which executes a sql query. The contents of the .bat file look like this:

```
sqlcmd -S ServerLocation -E -i "U:\DriveLocation\Sample.sql" -o "U:\DriveLocation\Sample_log.csv"
```

I'm running models on an AXIS processing grid which uses 60 Azure servers. When I try to run this .bat file using the Azure/cloud processors, nothing happens, but the file  works when I run it on my local machine.

Is it possible to run a .bat file on a group of Azure servers, or is there some code I need to include for it to work?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are doing. You say it "works when I run it on my local machine". I'm not clear what works: the grid, or the batch.  Are you trying to get the contents of the grid put into your .sql file for batch processing?  I'm also not sure what you mean by "60 grid engines", or if it has something to do with the problem.

Comment: "works when I run it on my local machine"--> When I run the .bat file on my local machine, the .bat file executes the sql query with no problem.  I'm trying to run the command within the .bat file on the grid.  "60 grid engines" isn't specific to the problem, and probably could have been excluded. Thanks! I hope that helps clarify the issue.

Comment: When you run the same bat file, but not on your machine, I guess it doesn't run.  Where is the bat file, and how are you running it (when it doesn't run)?  Perhaps, I'm thinking "grid" means data grid. Do you mean Azure cloud?

Comment: I'm running the .bat file using an Actuarial Modeling Software called AXIS.  AXIS has a built in macro which allows it to call .bat files.  The .bat file is located on a network drive which is set up to run models.  Within AXIS, there is an option to run the .bat macro on my local machine or to run the .bat file on the remote grid.  When I select to run it on the remote grid, it doesn't run the sql query.

Comment: yes, it is an Azure cloud

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this. Instead of using the AXIS model to run the .bat file on the Azure cloud, I created a .bat file outside of the AXIS model which would execute the model, then execute the .bat which I was trying to run with AXIS.

The script to run AXIS looks like this:

```
"C:\AXIS.exe" -D:C:\AXIS_Model -B:1
```

Where -B:1 specifies to run batch 1 in the model.

The script I was going to run in AXIS would just be another line in the .bat file:

```
"C:/AlteryxEngineCmd.exe" "U:\sampleworkflow.yxmd"
```

Thanks!